# Understanding android dimensions

Tags: android, dimensions, dpi

I have two devices the Desire HD (217dpi, 4,3") and the Nexus 7 (216dpi, 7"). I'm actually building the menu and get crazy about the dimensions. I'm using in general dp (Density-independent Pixels).

Our designer wants that the options are a little bigger than default so I added an `android:minHeight="100dp"` to the base of my `ListView` item. But it looks very different on the tablet and the mobile. Here is a screenshot I resized the tablet screenshot to 62% so both screenshots are equal height.

[image: two screenshots]

However both options are 100dp height but as you can see the gaps are very different on the table they are about 0.5/1/0.5 which looks nice but on the mobile this is 1/1/1 which looks bad. I don't understand why this happens.

I have also a counter as you can see both in the yellow box both are 100% scaled the tablet makes a rectangle with rounded edges while on the mobile it's more like a circle. Both are using the same shape xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#fff" />
    <solid android:color="#f00" />
    <padding android:left="4dp"
             android:top="2dp"
             android:right="4dp"
             android:bottom="2dp" /> 
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Why do those images looks so different? I tried to compare the dpi values which are almost the same. I think both devices have the density hdpi. So I cannot use a separate values file based on the dpi, I could use the large prefix but I'm not sure how this would look on a bigger tablet.

Comment: What are your values for textSize?

Comment: I don't set it I'm using `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`.

Comment: Try to use sp as a dimension and see if you'll still get this discrepancy, it may be possible that "Large" is not the same on phone and tablet in dips?

Comment: I tried 17sp. No significant changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this behavior. It is the font size settings on that device. It was set to *Huge* so all demensions with the unit **SP** where multiplayed by 1.5. You can check it for your device in the settings with Settings -> Display -> Font Size.

As I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16558314/995926) you can get the scale factor with this simple line of code:

```
float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
```

My solution is to use that scale factor or not to mix up **SP** with **DP**.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because both devices has the same DPI but different pixels and screen size in inch.
For Android both are HDPI (because of the 216-217dpi). You can solve this by:

1. Create a dedicated layout for nexus 7 or tablet with 7".
2. Create a dedicated style for nexus 7, something like values-sw600dp/styles.xml
3. Adapt the layout to add a bigger dimension.

I think the "Google solution" will be to create a different layout for tablets, as you have more space and screen. Check the Gmail or Google play app.

Basically if your app need to work well on tablets you have to add two new folders for layouts and values:

1. layout-sw600dp ---> nexus 7 or 7" tablets
2. layout-sw720dp ---> nexus 10 or 10" tablets

Hopes this help!!

Comment: I was thinking about somthing like that but what does `layout-sw720dp` mean exactly I know this is a switch but what does sw mean?

Comment: sw means screen width i believe. sw600dp is for 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger) and sw720dp is for 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger).

Comment: But the Nexus 7 has 800x1280. So it would grep `sw720dp`? [sw means smallest width](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: Is for small width, take a look at:http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali

Comment: If your problem is specifically nexus 7, check this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html

Comment: @NicolasJafelle I have right now just those both devices. So far I don't know.

Comment: I think that is something about the user defined font scaling (Settings -> Display -> Font Size). It seems that the solution is to use SP instad of DP.

Answer (score 0):

set The height of your listview manually in your code using this

```
  int height= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
```

Comment: Well this is an option, but I would prefer something in xml. Anyway this does not slove the second problem about the notifications (yellow box).

Comment: I think that is something about the user defined font scaling (Settings -> Display -> Font Size). It seems that the solution is to use SP instad of DP.